# Suppose $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is a decreasing sequence with limit $0$. Prove that $(b_n)$ is a decreasing sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $(a_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is a decreasing sequence with limit $0$. Define $$b_n=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}}{n}$$ Prove that $(b_n)$ is a decreasing sequence. My attempt is consider $$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}=(\frac{n}{n+1})(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}{a_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}}) \leq (\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}{a_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}})=1+\frac{a_{n+1}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}}$$ Then i stuck here. I don know how to show $\frac{a_{n+1}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}} \leq 0$ or it is not true itself. Any one can guide me ?

Comment: Your estimation is too strong. As $a_i>0$, clearly we have, $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}{a_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}}>1$$.

Comment: This is intuitively clear.  You are taking the average of the terms of a decreasing sequence.  Since $a_n$ is decreasing, out of all the terms $a_1, \ldots, a_{n+1}$, $a_{n+1}$ is going to be the smallest, so less than the avearge of $a_1, \ldots, a_n$.  Thus, when you add it in and take the average, the average must decrease.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align} b_n-b_{n+1} &=\frac{(n+1)\sum_{i\le n}a_i -  n\sum_{i\le n+1} a_i}{n(n+1)} =  \\ &=
\frac{\sum_{i\le n}a_i - na_{n+1}}{n(n+1)} = \frac{\sum_{i\le n}(a_i -a_{n+1})}{n(n+1)} \ge 0  \end{align}$$
where $a_i\ge a_{n+1}$is used for all $i=1,\dots, n$.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you have to show,
$$b_{n}\geq b_{n+1}$$
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}}{n}\geq \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}{a_i}}{n+1}$$
$$n\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}\geq n\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}+na_{n+1}$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}\geq na_{n+1}$$
It's clearly true since {$a_i$} is decreasing. You'll over-complicate things to compare in form of a fraction.